# makefile for libsvmerror.code usingg cygwin

Tags: makefile, cygwin

I am trying to run the makefile using the cygwin. But it is giving me error.

Makefile :

```
CXXC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -O3 

all: svm-train svm-predict svm-scale

svm-predict: svm-predict.c svm.o
    $(CXXC) $(CFLAGS) svm-predict.c svm.o -o svm-predict -lm
svm-train: svm-train.c svm.o
    $(CXXC) $(CFLAGS) svm-train.c svm.o -o svm-train -lm
svm-scale: svm-scale.c
    $(CXXC) $(CFLAGS) svm-scale.c -o svm-scale
svm.o: svm.cpp svm.h
    $(CXXC) $(CFLAGS) -c svm.cpp
clean:
    rm -f *~ svm.o svm-train svm-predict svm-scale
```

The image : [image]

I tried typing make, Makefile.. it is not working... Need some help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install Make as part of Cygwin:

[image: Type make into search field and select make from category Devel]

Comment: when i type make now : $ make
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.

Comment: @lakesh Well, this means that everything is up-to-date, and your screenshot proves that: `svm-train`, `svm-predict` and `svm-scale` have already been built.

Comment: @lakesh, obviusly, `./svm-train`.

Comment: it gives me this error: ./svm-train
-bash: ./svm-train: cannot execute binary file

Comment: @lakesh, AFAIK, this can happen because of wrong permissions on the executable, try `chmod 0755 svm-train`. Another possible reason is different architecture (32- or 64-bit) of your OS and the executable. Try adding `-m32` or `-m64` option to `CFLAGS` (second line of the Makefile), then `make clean all` and running you executable again.

Comment: @lakesh: To force rebuilding of everything you just type `make clean all`.